# Automaticly add CV-qualified functions

Tags: c++, parameters

I have next class

```
class Parameter
{
private:
    T value_;

public:
    // Get
    T& value()                                 { return value_; }
    volatile T& value() volatile               { return value_; }
    const T& value() const                     { return value_; }
    const volatile T& value() volatile const   { return value_; }
}
```

How can I minimize number of lines, amount of code. I want to write once `T& value()` and achieve CV-qualified versions automatically. Possible?

Comment: Do you often use `const volatile` objects? I have never seen any.

Comment: You might want to write a simple code generator.

Comment: I've done something similar using macros.

Comment: @Arun, KeithM, yes I believe I can do it via macros. May be it is possible via templates?

Comment: @BoPersson, really never. But ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use macro, but I can't see any use of such:

```
#define IDK_WHY(returnType, functionName, functionArgs, functionBody) \
                   returnType functionName functionArgs                functionBody \
    volatile       returnType functionName functionArgs volatile       functionBody \
    const          returnType functionName functionArgs const          functionBody \
    const volatile returnType functionName functionArgs volatile const functionBody

class Parameter
{
    using T = int; //for testing, dunno what is T in your code
private:
    T value_;

public:
    // note you can't use comma in last argument, it would require more complex macro
    IDK_WHY(T&, value, (), { return value_;}) //done
};
```

Comment: Ugly. but works. Simply as C. Fastest solution as for me. I don't like it, but use. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to expose every reference to a variable, expose the variable.

Now `p.value_` does exactly what you want.

Barring that, the easiest way is to write:

```
template< class A, class B >
using same_test = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same< std::decay_t<A>, std::decay_t<B> >{}, int>
```

then inside the class write:

```
template<class Self, same_test<Self, Parameter> =0>
friend decltype(auto) get_value( Self&& self ) {
  return decltype(self)(self).value_;
}
```

now `get_value( p )` will return `p.value` with the right l/r/cv qualifications.

If you don't like that syntax, I can provide you with `(p->*value)()`:

```
template<class F>
struct magic_method_ptr_t {
  F f;
  template<class Lhs>
  friend auto operator->*(Lhs&& lhs, magic_method const& m) {
    return [&](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto) {
      return m.f( decltype(lhs)(lhs), decltype(args)(args)... );
    };
  }
};
template<class F>
magic_method_ptr_t<F> magic_method_ptr( F f ) { return {std::move(f)}; }

auto value = magic_method_ptr( [](auto&& x){ return get_value(decltype(x)(x)); }
```

Add this to the `get_value` case above, and `(p->*value)()` works.

I cannot provide you with `p.value()` syntax, barring ugly macros.

Comment: Can exactly say what C++ std need this code? Any GCC extensions?

Comment: @kyb  as far as I can tell, I just used bog standard C++14.  There could be typos.  Yes, I missed a `friend` on `operator->*`.  Note the `(p->*value)()` syntax presumes you have already implemented `get_value` above: it is just syntactic sugar to call `get_value` for you (and I'm not sure how sweet the sugar is).

Comment: thank you for detailed answer, but it is not the same I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be with the usage of macros. Maybe is less elegant, but it's very simple, clear and powerful.

You may define a macro simply taking the member variable name and writing each getter (you can explode that with setter and other utilities as well).

```
/// @param X is the variable name
/// @param Y is the get name. The result will be get_##Y
#define create_getters(X, Y) decltype(X)& get_##Y() {   \
    return this->X; \
  } \
  const decltype(X)& get_##Y() const { \
    return this->X; \
  }

// Example class
class Foo {
  std::string m_data;

 public:
  // expose m_data as get_Data()
  create_getters(m_data, Data);  // Actually you don't need ; here
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Foo f;
  auto&& r = f.get_Data();  // ref
  auto&& cr = static_cast<const Foo&>(f).get_Data();  // const-ref

  return 0;
}
```