# Is there way to add const modifier to func through templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two similar functions, which I want to make through one template function:

```
A& get(void);
const A& get(void) const;
```

I want to create magic template function:

```
template <bool IsConst>
std::conditional<IsConst, const A&, A&> get(void) ???? make through template
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: almost looks like you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498501/automaticly-add-cv-qualified-functions)

Comment: The best solution for the actual problem would probably teaching your text editor to generate the second overload for you.

Comment: I would love for there to be a nice way to do this. But that would involve somebody doing some careful work, writing a new language proposal, etc.